# Relation between one double recursive formula and numbers q-binomial

Tags: binomial-coefficients, recursive-algorithms

Take $q$ a primitive $r$-root of unit, that is $q^r=1$ and $q^k \neq 1$, for all $k<r$. Consider the following expression defined by double recursive formula:
$$ F(l,n) = q^{-l}F(l,n-1) - q^{-l}F(l+1,n-1) \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ F(l,0)=\delta_{l,0} $$
we also assume that $F(l+r,n) = F(l,n)$.

Let $\displaystyle {n \choose k}_q$ by the $q$-binomial number, which can be defined also recursively by
$$ {n \choose k}_q = q^k{n-1 \choose k}_q + {n-1 \choose k-1}_q $$
also,
$$ {0 \choose 0}_q = 1, \ \ \ \ {n \choose k}_q=0, \textrm{ if } k>n. $$
Now that my question is if the following formula is satisfied:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{t(n-k)}{n \choose k}_qF(l+t, n+m-k)F(l+m-k,k)= \\
 = \sum_{k=0}^{n}q^{tk}{n \choose k}_qF(l, n-k)F(l+m+t-k,m+k).
\end{eqnarray}
I already know that it works for $r=2,3$ by hand.